# Auto Layout custom view crashes when resized

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

My custom view, a multi-selection enabled action sheet, crashes whenever it's size is changed and then added as a subview, or whenever it's resized after it's been added. My errors say that my constraints are conflicting, but I can't understand why. I've been using a similar pattern for all my other custom views (view = [Bundle loadNibNamed], view.frame = presenter.view.frame+modifiers) and they all work fine, with their constraints too.

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc588920 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0xc18d290(480)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc129980 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0xd8c6210.height == SWRevealView:0xd8c5f40.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xd8ccb80 h=-&- v=-&- SWRevealView:0xd8c5f40.height == UIWindow:0xc18d290.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc5aa660 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0xc5a3d90.height == UIView:0xd8c6210.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xda96c20 V:[UIButton:0xda99260(45)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xda89310 V:|-(427)-[UITableView:0xe855c00]   (Names: '|':MultiSelectionSheet:0xdaac360'Select Filters' )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xda8c1d0 V:[UITableView:0xe855c00]-(1)-[UIButton:0xda99260]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xda6d520 V:[UIButton:0xda99260]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':MultiSelectionSheet:0xdaac360'Select Filters' )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc5962c0 h=-&- v=-&- MultiSelectionSheet:0xdaac360'Select Filters'.height == UILayoutContainerView:0xc5a3d90.height>"
```

[image: constraints]

[image: layout]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4510" systemVersion="12F37" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES">
<dependencies>
    <deployment defaultVersion="1536" identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3742"/>
</dependencies>
<objects>
    <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
    <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="1" customClass="MultiSelectionSheet">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
        <subviews>
            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" showsHorizontalScrollIndicator="NO" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" allowsMultipleSelection="YES" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mXD-gg-Pfl">
                <rect key="frame" x="5" y="20" width="310" height="482"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                <inset key="separatorInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
            </tableView>
            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="emp-R8-XZ7">
                <rect key="frame" x="5" y="503" width="310" height="45"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.27450980390000002" green="0.76470588240000004" blue="0.83529411760000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="45" id="Ykt-VQ-0SN"/>
                </constraints>
                <state key="normal" title="DONE">
                    <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </state>
                <connections>
                    <action selector="dismissTable:" destination="1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="b33-Bh-apy"/>
                </connections>
            </button>
        </subviews>
        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.26408531021897808" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
        <constraints>
            <constraint firstItem="mXD-gg-Pfl" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="1" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="2zC-KQ-ZOt"/>
            <constraint firstItem="emp-R8-XZ7" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="1" secondAttribute="leading" constant="5" id="6gg-Py-tQZ"/>
            <constraint firstItem="emp-R8-XZ7" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="mXD-gg-Pfl" secondAttribute="trailing" id="9cH-nC-BFj"/>
            <constraint firstItem="emp-R8-XZ7" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="mXD-gg-Pfl" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="1" id="MFF-2J-4nH"/>
            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="emp-R8-XZ7" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="5" id="OxD-y5-2uC"/>
            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="emp-R8-XZ7" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" symbolic="YES" id="cnS-12-qe0"/>
            <constraint firstItem="mXD-gg-Pfl" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="emp-R8-XZ7" secondAttribute="leading" id="kWm-ho-P3w"/>
        </constraints>
        <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
        <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
        <connections>
            <outlet property="dismissButton" destination="emp-R8-XZ7" id="Nwx-Xh-wGZ"/>
            <outlet property="sheetTable" destination="mXD-gg-Pfl" id="REB-gn-MlB"/>
            <outlet property="spaceAboveTable" destination="2zC-KQ-ZOt" id="uAY-xN-L78"/>
        </connections>
    </view>
</objects>
```

setting `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstrainsts = NO` will allow the view to be drawn, but with dubious sizes and inaccurate frame sizes. Moreover, while set to NO, setting a static instead of dynamic height on the tableview will give more layout conflicts

Comment: Can you attach .xib file?

Comment: Added the sheet xib as xml - the presenting view is a Storyboard UINavigationController

Comment: turn off autoresizingMask. In code you go `myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`, I'm sure there tick box for it on the view in the storyboard too.

Comment: while that does allow the view to be draw, it's then stretched out of shape. it collapses the whole table and shrinks the button to fit it's text, and the view floats somewhere around 40px down. Despite this, frame is still reading as 0x0,320x480

Comment: I was able to solve the squashing by only disabling translatesAutoresizing on subviews, not the entire view

Comment: Provide the code that displays the custom view "action sheet".